# magento datetime attribute getting inserted in wrong format

Tags: magento

I created an attribute for customer entity like this

```
$setup->addAttribute( 'customer', 'created_time', array(
        'type'                => 'datetime',
        'input'                => 'date',
        'backend' => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_datetime',
        'label'                => 'Created Time',`enter code here`
        'required'            => false,
        'visible'            => true,
    )
);
```

and when I am trying to insert the date as `yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s` format. It is getting inserted in `yyyy-dd-mm` format. I don't know why this is happening. When I tried to insert date as yyyy-dd-mm H:i:s then it got inserted properly in the format `yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s`.

But if I update any info of customer again the value for attribute changes for that customer to yyyy-dd-mm again.

Don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 4):

May be this can help someone.

This method can solve the problem in **Magento 1.9**.

In a few words, your just need rewrite Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Datetime model in your module and add your model name in ‘backend’ param.

1) Create model in your module:
Path: yourCompany\yourModule\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\Datetime.php

```
class yourCompany_yourModule _Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Datetime extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Datetime
{
/**
 * Prepare date for save in DB
 *
 * string format used from input fields (all date input fields need apply locale settings)
 * int value can be declared in code (this meen whot we use valid date)
 *
 * @param   string | int $date
 * @return  string
 */
public function formatDate($date)
{
    if (empty($date)) {
        return null;
    }
    // unix timestamp given - simply instantiate date object
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $date)) {
        $date = new Zend_Date((int)$date);
    }
    // international format
    else if (preg_match('#^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}( \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})?$#', $date)) {
        $zendDate = new Zend_Date();
        $date = $zendDate->setIso($date);
    }
    // parse this date in current locale, do not apply GMT offset
    else {
        $date = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date($date,
            Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT),
            null, false
        );
    }
    return $date->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
}
```

}

This model does only one thing, replaces the name of one method

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT)
```

to another

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT)
```

2) Add attribute

```
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->startSetup();
$setup->addAttribute( 'customer', 'created_time', array(
    'type'      => 'datetime',
    'input'     => ' datetime ',
    'backend'   => 'yourModelNamespace/entity_attribute_backend_datetime',
    'label'     => 'Created Time',
    'required'  => false,
    'visible'   => true,
    )
);
$setup->endSetup();
```

3) For complete beginners. You can find yourModelNamespace here.
Path:  yourCompany\yourModule\etc\config.xml

```
<global>
    <models>
        <yourModelNamespace>
            <class>yourCompany_yourModule_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>yourModelNamespace_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </yourModelNamespace>
    </models>
</global>
```

**Another method:**

1) Copy file 
Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\Datetime.php
to local code pool
Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\Rightdatetime.php
with new name. To avoid unpredictable problems.

2) Replace getDateFormat on getDateTimeFormat

3) In db in "eav_attribute" table update your attribute field "backend_model" eav/entity_attribute_backend_rightdatetime